# How do i get correct version of maven dependencies for hibernate and spring?

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, dependencies

I am new to programming and I am using eclipse mars. I am using maven, spring 4.4(3.6.2), and hibernate.
How do I get correct version dependencies for spring and hibernate?
How do i include it in my pom.xml file

Comment: What is Eclipse Mars?

Comment: Maybe you should get the Spring Tool Suite plugin for Eclipse. I don't think they have a Mars version yet, but you can try and add the Luna version, and see how it plays with each other. The plugin will allow you to create Spring startup projects. Or maybe just download [Spring Tool Suite](http://spring.io/tools/sts). If you're new to Spring you'll will quickly find out that dependency management is a pain. So any tools to help you will it will be to your advantage.

Comment: @DUKE Eclipse Mars is the current development version of Eclipse, highly unstable and i can't understand that someone is really using it for development, especially when he doesn't know the versions of the libraries he is using (see Spring 4.4, which doesn't exist).

Comment: For now i am stupid of using eclipse and spring, since i have just started. I really don't know which version of spring and hibernate i have installed. I searched for the latest eclipse and downloaded mars, but when i searched for spring for mars i couldn't get so i installed spring for Luna which showed spring 4.4(3.6.2) at the market place that is why i said "spring 4.4(3.6.2)". Can you suggest me which version of eclipse and other supporting components should i use? (i searched for spring as follows "Help>Eclipse Marketplace" and searched spring).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How Do you want to say with **How do I get correct version dependencies for spring and hibernate**. Le latest version of spring is 4.1.1 while te latest version of hibernate is 4.3.7.Final.

You can include them in your pom in the following way:

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

This is the way that allow you to add dependencies in your project. Then for spring you have to know that it is a modular application container, then when you add the spring dependencies you have to know what you need. For example if you have to build a web application you have to add spring MVC.